# docker buildx build failed to push image because dns resolve failed

Tags: docker, build, buildx, harbor

I want to push multi-structure image to a private harbor registry like below.

```
docker buildx build --add-host=local-habor.com:10.11.140.68 \
    --builder mybuilder -t local-habor.com/test/test1:v1 \
    --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -f Dockerfile-multi2 \
    --push .
```

I have `local-habor.com` --> `10.11.140.68` configured in `/etc/hosts`, but it seems it is not recognized in Docker, with or without `--add-host=local-habor.com:10.11.140.68`.

The error is:

> ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push local-habor.com/test/test1:v1:
> failed to do request: Head
> "https://local-habor.com/v2/test/test1/blobs/sha256:e16b9c9f3907115a8c25e2f4be9dc3adf3cb1a2f657594b50c065fc99839bed5":
> dial tcp: lookup local-habor.com on 192.168.200.2:53: no such host

env:
ubuntu : Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Version:          25.0.3
API version:      1.44 (minimum version 1.24)
Go version:       go1.21.6

I tried `--add-host=local-habor.com:10.11.140.68` to force host resolve, but it seems not working.

I expect there is a way to configure DNS resolve in image pushing execution of during below command.